# I am using i-macro on a website to perform different actions on a site

Tags: imacros

I want i-macro to do something like this:

1 - go to specific url like: http://www.xyz.com
2 - if there is an error in loading the url, then perform this thing

TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:http://www.xyz.com

3 - else load the page

my question is how can i accomplish this task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is no IF statement in imacros you'll need to use javascript (for example). the code would be like this:

```
var ret=iimPlay("code:url goto=http://xyz.com");
if (ret<0){
iimPlay("code:TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:http://www.xyz.com");
}
else{
iimPlay("code:refresh");
}
```

save it as js file and run in firefox imacros.

Comment: Yeah awesome indeed. I use somewhat different solutions but still this hits it.